# Python стоит ли ставить переменную перед циклом for для оптимизации

Tags: python, python-3.x

Поможет ли по настоящему выносить переменные из цикла для оптимизации кода?
Что лучше?

```
i = 5
for x in range(10):
    i = input()
    print(i)
```

Или

```
for x in range(10):
    i=input()
    print(i)
```

Ведь по сути убирается создание переменной на каждой итерации цикла, получается лучше использовать первый вариант?

Comment: Если Вы собираетесь использовать переменную далее вне цикла, тогда безусловно стоит, в противном случае не имеет никакого смысла. (Хотя в приведенном Вами примере - пофиг)

Comment: В python область видимости переменных - либо функция, либо модуль, но не логическая область ограниченная табуляцией (или фигурными скобками как в c++). Т.е. в обоих случаях переменная создается только один раз и будет доступна после выхода из цикла..

Comment: посмотрел в `dis.dis`, единственное изменение это две инструкции перед циклом во втором примере: `LOAD_CONST` и `STORE_NAME`. А содержимое цикла абсолютно идентично